# Driver not recognized with Windows Guest VirtualBox and Ipod Nano

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtualbox, drivers, ipod

I'm having a driver problem with my ipod nano. I'm trying to connect my nano to my windows guest vbox with a linux host. Although the system is recognizing the nano, it says that there is a driver problem. I tried allowing the system to troubleshoot the driver and it didn't work. How do I get the Windows VBox guest to recognize the iPod?

Here's what the log said when I tried to troubleshoot it:

> PrintDevices and Printers Publisher details
>
> Issues found 
>   USB Mass Storage Device has a driver problemUSB Mass Storage Device has a driver problem
>   There is a problem with the driver for USB Mass Storage Device. The driver needs to be reinstalled. Not fixed
>   Reinstall device driver Completed
>
> Problem with PnP devicesProblem with PnP devices
>   There are problems with some PnP devices. Windows will take additional steps to further troubleshoot these devices. Detected Detected 
>   Potential issues that were checked 
>   Windows Update configured to never install driversWindows Update configured to never install drivers
>   Driver updates aren't automatically installed when detected by Windows Update. Issue not present
>
> Issues found Detection details
>
> 6 USB Mass Storage Device has a driver problem Not fixed Not Fixed
>
> There is a problem with the driver for USB Mass Storage Device. The driver needs to be reinstalled. 
>   InformationalDevice information 
>   Name: USB Mass Storage Device 
>   ID: USB\VID_05AC&PID_1301\000A27001C62DFDA 
>   Error code: 10
>
> Reinstall device driver Completed
>
> There is a problem with the driver for USB Mass Storage Device. Reinstalling the driver might fix this problem.
>
> Problem with PnP devices Detected Detected
>
> There are problems with some PnP devices. Windows will take additional steps to further troubleshoot these devices.
>
> Potential issues that were checked Detection details
>
> Windows Update configured to never install drivers Issue not present
>
> Driver updates aren't automatically installed when detected by Windows Update.
>
> Detection details Expand
>
> Collection information 
>   Computer Name:  A***-WINDOWS 
>   Windows Version: 6.1 
>   Architecture: amd64 
>   Time: Thursday, February 06, 2014 12:18:04 AM

Comment: Looks like this problem is not just specific to my ipod Nano. This is also affecting all my other usb devices.

Answer (score 11):

I got the same problem( Error code: 10) with guest OS win7 and host ubuntu 14.04. The problem was usb2.0 was not enabled in virtualbox. And to enable that I needed to download virtualbox extension pack and install it in virtualbox main prefe. (Mine was version 4.3.10). And after that in my virtual machine settings (it should be switched off) > USB > clicked 'Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller' checkbox.

After I restarted and everything started working (itunes also detected my ipad).

In your case, if USB2.0 is not enabled follow the steps below

1. Download virtual extension pack for your virtualbox version.
2. Install it using virtualbox main window preferences. (Not in an individual virtual machine window. i.e open virtualbox main window > File > Preferences > Extensions)
3. Add the downloaded extension.
4. Go to your virtual machine settings > USB > enable  USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller.
5. Restart the virtual machine.

Comment: usb 2.0 requires 'extension pack' which is not available on most linux distros.

Comment: Worked for me too with an external USB HDD. Make sure to check out the Extension Pack license, it's not the same one as the base package

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that although I allowed the USB devices on the system itself, it needed to be added directly to the usb settings on the virtualbox client.

If you have this problem make sure that you go to Settings -> USB -Enable USB 2.0 Controller -> add any filters.

Note: It did not work for me when I just added the USB devices on the menu of the guest!!! Driver problems despite detection led me astray in troubleshooting.